# Postgres - copying a table from a dump file

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a database dump that I generated with pg_dump, like so:

```
pg_dump -C remote_db -a --no-owner -t my_table > dump.sql
```

and I'm looking to copy a single table over from it into my local database, with data only (not schema) and with no ownership settings. I'm familiar with how to do it directly from another db using pg_dump, something like:

```
pg_dump -C remote_db -a --no-owner -t my_table | psql local_db
```

But I'm not sure how to replicate the same effect from a file.

I've tried something like:

```
pg_restore -d local_db -a --no-owner -t my_table dump.sql
```

But got an error:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

I'm not sure how to use psql to achieve the same thing. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you produce `dump.sql` ? Please add *all* the *exact* commands that you used to your question.

Comment: Added what I used to generate the dump to the question.

Comment: `psql local_db < dump.sql` should do it. See http://www.westwind.com/reference/os-x/commandline/pipes.html for how those I/O redirects work.